# How can i load a table on changing a select option using AHAH callback

Tags: 6, forms, ajax

I have drop down in a form as follows and i want to load a table of data using the drop down value , here is i have tried ,

```
function list_user_form(){
     $form['howmany'] = array(
    '#title' => t('List all the users in a group'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => select_usergroup_dropdown_options(),
    '#default_value' => $default,
    '#ahah' => array(
      'path' => 'mailusers/listuserstable',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),

  );
   $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Me'),
  );
   return $form;
}

function listuserstable(){
//make html for the table and rendering it 
}
```

But unfortunately it gives me `403 error` , please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some wrapper to your table:

```
function list_user_form(){
   $form['howmany'] = array(
      '#title' => t('List all the users in a group'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => select_usergroup_dropdown_options(),
      '#default_value' => $default,
      '#ahah' => array(
         'path' => 'mailusers/listuserstable',
         'effect' => 'fade',
         'wrapper' => 'mytable'
      )
   );

   $form['mytable'] = array(
      '#title' => t("Generated table"),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="mytable">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#description' => t('This is where we get automatically generated table')
   );

   $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Click Me')
   );
   return $form;
}

function listuserstable(){
   // make html for the table and rendering it
}
```